# Error en mi conexión de Postgresql con python: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xf3 in position 85: invalid continuation byte

Tags: python, postgresql, utf-8, codificación

Estoy tratando de conectar mi base de datos y usar una interfaz pero no conecta.
Espero me puedan ayudar, solo necesito que conecte y haga un select por lo menos.

### formularioarticulos.py

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import messagebox as mb
from tkinter import scrolledtext as st
import productos

class FormularioProductos:
    def __init__(self):
        self.producto1=productos.Productos()
        self.ventana1=tk.Tk()
        self.ventana1.title("Mantenimiento de productos")
        self.cuaderno1 = ttk.Notebook(self.ventana1)        
        self.carga_productos()
        self.listado_completo()
        self.cuaderno1.grid(column=0, row=0, padx=10, pady=10)
        self.ventana1.mainloop()

    def carga_productos(self):
        self.pagina1 = ttk.Frame(self.cuaderno1)
        self.cuaderno1.add(self.pagina1, text="Carga de productos")
        self.labelframe1=ttk.LabelFrame(self.pagina1, text="Producto")        
        self.labelframe1.grid(column=0, row=0, padx=5, pady=10)
        self.label1=ttk.Label(self.labelframe1, text="Nombre:")
        self.label1.grid(column=0, row=0, padx=4, pady=4)
        self.nombrecarga=tk.StringVar()
        self.entrynombre=ttk.Entry(self.labelframe1, textvariable=self.nombrecarga)
        self.entrynombre.grid(column=1, row=0, padx=4, pady=4)
        self.label2=ttk.Label(self.labelframe1, text="Grados de alcohol:")        
        self.label2.grid(column=0, row=1, padx=4, pady=4)
        self.gradoscarga=tk.StringVar()
        self.entrygrados=ttk.Entry(self.labelframe1, textvariable=self.gradoscarga)
        self.entrygrados.grid(column=1, row=1, padx=4, pady=4)
        self.label3=ttk.Label(self.labelframe1, text="Stock:")        
        self.label3.grid(column=0, row=2, padx=4, pady=4)
        self.stockcarga=tk.StringVar()
        self.entrystock=ttk.Entry(self.labelframe1, textvariable=self.stockcarga)
        self.entrystock.grid(column=1, row=2, padx=4, pady=4)
        self.label4=ttk.Label(self.labelframe1, text="Precio:")        
        self.label4.grid(column=0, row=3, padx=4, pady=4)
        self.preciocarga=tk.StringVar()
        self.entryprecio=ttk.Entry(self.labelframe1, textvariable=self.preciocarga)
        self.entryprecio.grid(column=1, row=3, padx=4, pady=4)
        self.label5=ttk.Label(self.labelframe1, text="ID Categoría:")        
        self.label5.grid(column=0, row=4, padx=4, pady=4)
        self.categoriacarga=tk.StringVar()
        self.entrycategoria=ttk.Entry(self.labelframe1, textvariable=self.categoriacarga)
        self.entrycategoria.grid(column=1, row=4, padx=4, pady=4)
        self.boton1=ttk.Button(self.labelframe1, text="Confirmar", command=self.agregar)
        self.boton1.grid(column=1, row=5, padx=4, pady=4)

    def agregar(self):
        datos = (
            self.nombrecarga.get(),
            self.gradoscarga.get(),
            self.stockcarga.get(),
            self.preciocarga.get(),
            self.categoriacarga.get()
        )
        self.producto1.alta(datos)
        mb.showinfo("Información", "Los datos fueron cargados")
        self.nombrecarga.set("")
        self.gradoscarga.set("")
        self.stockcarga.set("")
        self.preciocarga.set("")
        self.categoriacarga.set("")

    def listado_completo(self):
        self.pagina3 = ttk.Frame(self.cuaderno1)
        self.cuaderno1.add(self.pagina3, text="Listado completo")
        self.labelframe1=ttk.LabelFrame(self.pagina3, text="Producto")
        self.labelframe1.grid(column=0, row=0, padx=5, pady=10)
        self.boton1=ttk.Button(self.labelframe1, text="Listado completo", command=self.listar)
        self.boton1.grid(column=0, row=0, padx=4, pady=4)
        self.scrolledtext1=st.ScrolledText(self.labelframe1, width=30, height=10)
        self.scrolledtext1.grid(column=0,row=1, padx=10, pady=10)

    def listar(self):
        respuesta = self.producto1.recuperar_todos()

        if respuesta is not None:
            self.scrolledtext1.delete("1.0", tk.END)
            for fila in respuesta:
                self.scrolledtext1.insert(tk.END, "ID:"+str(fila[0])+"\nNombre:"+fila[1]+"\nGrados de alcohol:"+str(fila[2])+"\nStock:"+str(fila[3])+"\nPrecio:"+str(fila[4])+"\nID Categoría:"+str(fila[5])+"\n\n")
        else:
            print("No se pudo recuperar datos. La variable respuesta es None.")

aplicacion1=FormularioProductos()
```

### productos.py

```
import psycopg2
from psycopg2 import extras

class Productos:

    def abrir(self):
        try:
            # Conectar con la base de datos usando UTF8
            conexion = psycopg2.connect(database="vinateria", user="dba", password="ccc", client_encoding="UTF8")
            print("Conexión exitosa")
            return conexion
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Error al abrir la conexión: {e}")
            return None

    def alta(self, datos):
        cone = self.abrir()
        if cone:
            cursor = cone.cursor()
            try:
                sql = "insert into productos(nombre_producto, grados_alcohol, stock, precio, id_categoria) values (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)"
                cursor.execute(sql, datos)
                cone.commit()
            except Exception as e:
                print(f"Error al insertar datos: {e}")
            finally:
                cursor.close()
                cone.close()

    def recuperar_todos(self):
        cone = self.abrir()
        if cone:
            # Usar DictCursor para obtener resultados como un diccionario
            cursor = cone.cursor(cursor_factory=extras.DictCursor)
            try:
                sql = "select id_producto, nombre_producto, grados_alcohol, stock, precio, id_categoria from productos"
                cursor.execute(sql)
                # Convertir las cadenas a UTF-8
                return [{key: str(value).encode('utf-8').decode('utf-8', 'ignore') for key, value in fila.items()} for fila in cursor.fetchall()]
            except Exception as e:
                print(f"Error al recuperar datos: {e}")
                return None
            finally:
                cursor.close()
                cone.close()
        else:
            print("No se pudo establecer la conexión.")
            return None
```

Comment: vinateria=# \l
                                            Listado de base de datos
    Nombre    |  Due±o   | Codificaci≤n |       Collate       |        Ctype        |        Privilegios
--------------+----------+--------------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------------
 vinateria    | dba      | UTF8         | en_US.utf8          | en_US.utf8          |

Comment: 0xF3 no es un byte valido en la codificación multibyte  UTF-8, por experiencia, en el 99% de los casos esa cadena es Latin-? (ISO8859). Ese byte codifica  la "ó" en ISO8859. Deberías aislar y especificar exactamente que linea y sentencia causa la excepción ¿viene de psycopg2 o de tus intentos de codifcacion/decodificacion de lo que recibes? HAce algun tiempo que no uso PostgreSQL/psycopg2 pero en teoría las cadenas provenientes de la consulta deberían ser objetos str (y por lo tanto UTF-8 que el la codificacion usada en str en Python 3)